# Can I categorize Steam games by their install location?

Tags: steam

I've got two drives in my PC at this time, a 500GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I've got Steam games installed across both drives, and games I play more often are kept on the SSD, while things I don't mind waiting a little extra time for hang out on the HDD.

I know Steam can filter games to show you a list of installed games only. But can this list be further sorted to show which games are installed on C: (SSD) or F: (HDD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam cannot do that for you automatically. But, what you can do is manually create categories in your library.

To do that, right click on a game and select "Set categories...". Once the window is opened, you will be able to select which category to put the game on (if you already created categories) or to create a new category by typing the name in the small text box and clicking "Add category".

You can also select multiple games at once by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and select indivual items or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select a range of items.

Comment: I suppose I could do that manually, but I've got other categories set up for stuff I need to play, etc. etc. I'll see what else comes in, but this will probably be the answer!